# How do I create blurred/semi-transparent pen effect in GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+, dropshadow

I have searched far and wide without success...

I am trying to accomplish what is more clearly described in the image....Which is create a blurred/semi-transparent drop shadow on a graphics object during a paint event.

The ultimate solution is a blurred/semi-transparent Pen, that I could pass to a path, but as I understand it, that is not possible.

Here is the image:

[image: http://www.cadframers.com/stackoverflow/stack_overflow_drop_shadow.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pen with an alpha set to, for example, half [128] (adjust to suit your needs), then draw your path, translate your path 1px west and 1px south and draw again, translate 2px east and draw, 2px north and draw, and 2px west and draw.  Should give you a blurry shadowy effect.

Comment: That does not accomplish what I am trying to do. Thanks anyway

Comment: you might try playing around with linear gradient brushes.  I don't have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [gradient brushes and pens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sdy66e6.aspx)?